# How to send 404 HTTP status code with Polymer Starter Kit

Tags: polymer, firebase-hosting, polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit

When starting a new project with the polymer starter kit 2, it comes with decent client side routing based on the PRPL pattern as described [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/toolbox/prpl).

This works fine on the front end for the end user. However, on requesting a page that does not exist, there is no proper 404 status code sent. This is not good for SEO, in my understanding.

Is there a recommended way of doing this properly? I understand there needs to be some server side logic to determine what response code to send, but I am not sure how to do that in a straightforward way.

I plan to host my app with Firebase hosting, so if there's a solution for that platform, I'm happy to learn about it. But my question is aimed towards a general way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Hosting has additional features that let you customize how your content is hosted. You can set & customize to your own specific need at `firebase.json` file.

Here [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites) describes detailed information at hosting side how to define all, customized.
Hope this page heps.

Comment: I guess you can make this work with predetermined routes, thanks! But when you want to throw a 404 when, for example, there's no database entry for an ID in the URL, I do not see how to achieve this.